# Share button for every sections

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating one page that is devided in several sections and all sections have special ID. I woulld like to add social media share buttons to each sections 
and when I click in share button, it share only first section.

My page is in this form:

```
<section id="page-one" class="intro">Content</section>
<section id="page-two" class="intro">Content1</section>
<section id="page-three" class="intro">Content2</section>
```

and share buttons are:

```
<ul class="share-menu">
   <li><a onclick="window.open('https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?url=http://oasistheme.com/proj2/#page-one&title=Helloo','name','height=520, width=600,toolbar=no,directories=no,status=no, menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes'); return false;" href="" target="_blank" class="socicon socicon-linkedin"></a></li>
   <li><a onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://oasistheme.com/proj2/#page-one','name','height=520, width=600,toolbar=no,directories=no,status=no, menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes'); return false;" href="" class="socicon socicon-facebook"></a></li>
   <li><a onclick="window.open('https://plus.google.com/share?url=URL','name','height=520, width=600,toolbar=no,directories=no,status=no, menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes'); return false;" href="" class="socicon socicon-googleplus"></a></li>
   <li><a onclick="window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=URL&text=TITLE&via=USERNAME&hashtags=HASHTAGS','name','height=520, width=600,toolbar=no,directories=no,status=no, menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes'); return false;" href="" class="socicon socicon-twitter"></a></li>
</ul>
```

In each section I have set the code with different links and for example in the "page-two" section, the links are in this form:

```
<ul class="share-menu">
   <li><a onclick="window.open('https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?url=http://oasistheme.com/proj2/#page-two&title=Helloo','name','height=520, width=600,toolbar=no,directories=no,status=no, menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes'); return false;" href="" target="_blank" class="socicon socicon-linkedin"></a></li>
   <li><a onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://oasistheme.com/proj2/#page-two','name','height=520, width=600,toolbar=no,directories=no,status=no, menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes'); return false;" href="" class="socicon socicon-facebook"></a></li>
   <li><a onclick="window.open('https://plus.google.com/share?url=URL','name','height=520, width=600,toolbar=no,directories=no,status=no, menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes'); return false;" href="" class="socicon socicon-googleplus"></a></li>
   <li><a onclick="window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=URL&text=TITLE&via=USERNAME&hashtags=HASHTAGS','name','height=520, width=600,toolbar=no,directories=no,status=no, menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes'); return false;" href="" class="socicon socicon-twitter"></a></li>
</ul>
```

P.S. Sections name ID are just as example in this case

Answer (score 1):

The only problem with your code is that parsing will remove '#' character, therefore anchor part is escaped.
ASCII for hash is *%23*, therefore your link should be

```
https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?url=http://oasistheme.com/proj2/%23page-one
```

---

**Additionally, you have a lot of code you are reusing.**

I would suggest (but possibilities are definitely not limited to):

- Creating simple function `share(network, url)` which would case check whenever *network* is linkedin, twitter, etc. Then the function share the passed *url*. You would call this via `onclick=""`.
- Remove `onclick=""` and add event listener instead. Retrieve parameters with js and call previously mentioned *share()* function.
- Go full javascript (or any js library) by adding `class="shareable"` to each section and add share buttons dynamically.

---

***UPDATE*** (based on authors comment on default title and description)

Please, read about sharing attributes for each network. Common sharing works by retrieving the *og tags* (afaik, facebook, some of the tags for twitter too, although twitter has their own). If they are not set, site title/description or page title/description is retrieved, depends on markup. You can only set them once per page.

**For Facebook**, you can replace meta tag content with js on share trigger, or, use [facebook sdk](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/web) ([working, full example](http://drib.tech/programming/dynamically-change-facebook-open-graph-meta-data-javascript)).

```js
function fbShare(url, title, description, image)
{
 FB.ui({
  method: 'share_open_graph',
  action_type: 'og.shares',
  action_properties: JSON.stringify({
   object: {
    'og:url': url,
    'og:title': title,
    'og:description': description,
    'og:image': image
   }
  })
 },
 function (response) {});
}
```

**For Linkedin and Twitter**, it's easier

```js
function linkedinShare(url, title, summary) {
  window.open('http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url='+url+'&title='+title+'&summary='+summary+'&source=');
}

function twitterShare(url, title) {
  window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?mini=true&text=RT @ [yourprofile] '+title+' ' + url);
}
```

**For Google**, you cannnot change anythink but url. They only accept url parameter. [On google+ docs, you can find attribute fetching workflow](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/).

Comment: Ilva Linde, thanks for your answer. I follow your idea and I think that it works, but now problem is that for each secitions, when I click Share (for example in Facebook), always take title and description of first section.

Comment: I updated my answer to cover other attributes than the url

Answer (score 0):

```html
<ul class="share-menu">
<li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?url=http://oasistheme.com/proj2/#page-one&title=Helloo" onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;">link1</a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://oasistheme.com/proj2/#page-one" onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;">link2</a></li>
<li><a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=URL" onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;">link3</a></li>
<li><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=URL&text=TITLE&via=USERNAME&hashtags=HASHTAGS" onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;">link4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: vicky patel, he continues to take only first item in first section.